# QGIS Graphical Modeler - Altitude offset / translation - Something wrong with my raster calculator (gdal) expression

Tags: qgis, gdal, raster-calculator, qgis-modeler, qgis-expression

I've recently started exploring QGIS' Graphical Modeler, and I want to build a model that will:

1. Iterate over a vector layer's features
2. Use these features as masks to extract from a raster
3. Calculate the MAX (max altitude) of that extracted raster, and finally
4. Subtract this MAX value from all points in that extracted raster, as to obtain a raster with only negative and 0 values.

So basically a model that will offset / translate raster z-values along the z-axis.

My current model (see below) does steps 1 to 3 just fine:
[image]

But at step 4 I get the following error message:
[image]

I'm not entirely sure, but I think it has to do with the expression I use in the gdal raster calculator:
[image]
[image]

I've also tried A-B before that, and changed it to A-(A*B) because of the same error message as above.

I know I could easily do this in python, but I want to understand my error here. Also, if someone knows about some algorithm that already does what I'm trying to do, I would love to hear about it (but would also still like to understand the error I did :p).

Comment: B is for a raster not a value, try inputting the max into the expression. I don't know the syntax, but I mean something like A-A*@max